# When did Ash and the gang get ultra guardian suits?

Tags: pokemon

As in, when did this *ultra beast* Suit Control Room and elevator get installed?

It's a cool new series of Pokémon, but when was this room made?

Answer (score 2):

Ash is invited to join the Ultra Guardians by Lusamine in "The Professors' New Adventure!", the 55th episode of ''Pokemon Sun and Moon''. He goes on his first mission with the Ultra Guardians - and suits up for the first time - in "A Mission of Ultra Urgency!", the 61st episode of ''Sun and Moon'' (and coincidentally, the 1,000th episode overall).

I don't believe there's ever any indication of when the control room under the school was built.